# Alternative definition of a matroid?

Tags: axioms, matroids

$\mathcal M\,$ is a nonempty subset of the set of all subsets of the finite set $X$, such that:

$(1)\quad\; \neg\exists U,V\in\mathcal M:U\subset V\quad$

$(2)\quad\; A\subseteq B\in\mathcal M\wedge C\in\mathcal M\Rightarrow
\exists U\subseteq C:A\cup U\in\mathcal M$, alternatively

---

If $\;\mathcal I=\{U\subseteq X|\exists V\in\mathcal M:U\subseteq V\}$, is $(X,\mathcal I)$ a matroid then?

And reverse, if $\mathcal M$ is the set of all maximal independent sets in $\mathcal I$, for any matroid $(X,\mathcal I)$ does $\mathcal M$ satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: I've became interested in matroids but feels that the traditional definitions are awkward. So I'm trying to design an alternative definition. I think it's OK, but I lack the experience and confidence to determine for sure.

Comment: Well, it's not quite right. At most $\mathcal M$ could be the set of all non unitary maximal independent sets in $\mathcal I$.

Comment: Check out http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/shortcourse/2011/crypto.pdf - it is a very intersting article that features many different defintions of a matroid.

Comment: @Moritz: Thanks!!